# Using background-attachment:fixed in safari on the ipad

Tags: css, ipad, html

I'm looking to recreate an effect similiar to the popular science app. Basically have one big background image and then have HTML/CSS layer on top of that. When the user scrolls the content, then background-position of the image should remain in place, and not scroll.

Obviously in a 'regular' browser I would use background-attachment:fixed, but this doesn't seem to work on the ipad. I know position:fixed doesn't work as you might expect according to safari spec - but is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed background image with ios7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443574/fixed-background-image-with-ios7)

Answer (score 16):

You can use this code to make a fixed background layer to hack into this problem.

```
#background_wrap {
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: url('xx.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

And put `<div id="background_wrap"></div>` into `<body></body>`

```
<body>
<div id="background_wrap"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on Anlai's answer above, I found that solution was repeating my image as I was scrolling rather than keeping it fixed. If anyone else had this problem my CSS for the background_wrap ID is as follows:

```
#background_wrap {
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('../images/compressed/background-mobile.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

Just changed the background size and background attachment to make the image static.

Answer (score 2):

Mobile safari scales your whole site down to it's viewport size, including the background image. To achieve the correct effect, use the -webkit-background-size CSS property to declare your background size:

```
-webkit-background-size: 2650px 1440px;
```

(hat tip to commenter [Mac](http://teknocat.org/blog/web-development/show/6/mobile-safari-background-image-scaling-quirk))

Comment: It does not work. Demo: with an iPad (mine is a Pro, iOS 11.3), surf to https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment. Add the line `-webkit-background-size: 200px 358px;`, click 'Run' and see for yourself. Also, the Mac link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can place the background image in a div and set the z-index to appear behind other content.  Afterwards you can use javascript to fix the position of the div which contains the background image.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that profi one, but I've solved this problem usin' jquery.
It's quite simple)
Here is the code:

```js
 jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
  var fromtop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  jQuery(" your element ").css({"background-position-y": fromtop+"px"});
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Similar to Ig365, I found that Angolao's solution causes image repeat, depending on image proportions; however, Ig365's image doesn't mimic the placement of `background-fixed` . To do this, add a `background-position-x: 50%;`. (Depending on your image dimensions, you may also need `background-position-y: 50%`.)

```css
#background_wrap {
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('imageURL');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

next solution in Css:

```
body {
  background-image: url( ../images/fundobola.jpg );
  background-position: top center;background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 1900px 1104px;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

--- not use---- (cause: scroll disable )

```
position: fixed
```

Resolved in Ipad and iPhone

Comment: ...but `-moz-` is the Mozilla, not iPhone (= Webkit) prefix?

Comment: Does not work at all. Also what has `font-family:Arial;` and margins on body have to do with the solution?