# How to use CSS media query to scale background-image to viewing window

Tags: css, mobile, mobile-safari, background-image, media-queries

I have this large image as a background for a website:

```
body {
    background: #000 url(/assets/img/living.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
}
```

But on my mobile device (iPhone 4S - Safari), the `background-attachment: fixed` does't seem to be having the same effect as it would on a desktop. Why is that and can I use a media query to fix that?

Comment: What happens exactly ? Can you post a link to investigate ?

Comment: The mobile version of Safari probably doesn't support `background-attachment: fixed`. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011226/using-background-attachmentfixed-in-safari-on-the-ipad

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this - you don't always need a media query to handle background images.  The CSS3 background-size:cover property handles all that quite well on its own. The below works well for me on all mobile devices I've tested - especially well on Android, mobile version browsers and all tablets.

```
body { 
    background-image: url(/assets/img/living.jpg); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;       
    webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
    width:100%; 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately cover and fixed no-repeat background doesn't work in Android tablet, portrait mode.

Comment: add html{height:100%,width:100%} in your css.

Comment: @arp wow just wow. Thanks! That fixed my problem with background images not displaying on mobile consistently!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without serving a HUGE image? Say serve the mobile version if mobile and desktop if desktop to save on bandwidth and adjust to the actual device size?