# background image not showing in full size on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, background-image

I use this code to show image background:

```
body {
    background:url('images/bg.jpg')no-repeat center center fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

works good on desktop computer but when I look at the site in mobile (iPhone for ex) the image not reach the bottom of the screen and there is a white space after it.

*my image file size is: 1280X1007*

How can I fix that?

Comment: Hey @Italy can you show us live demo of your code....

Answer (score 0):

maybe a `body { height = 100%; margin = 0; ...}` is useful!?
What is the resolution of your iPhone and can you try it on other devices with Safari-Browser?

Comment: just found another thread, talking about "CSS3 background-size:cover property" especially for mobile devices.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687778/how-to-use-css-media-query-to-scale-background-image-to-viewing-window?rq=1