# Trying to stretch background to 100% height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a full page div (with 100% width & height). But in firefox it is not stretching fully. Here's my code:-

```
div{
    background:url('image.jpg')no-repeat fixed;
    background-size:cover;
 }
```

I've tried a lot,but I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Where are you setting height and width?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687778/how-to-use-css-media-query-to-scale-background-image-to-viewing-window

Comment: its all 100%, I just added the relevent code only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there's nothing wrong with your CSS as such, but in order for it to work properly you need to(unfortunately) add browser prefix
try adding

```
 div{
    background:url('image.jpg')no-repeat fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
  }
```

Comment: Indeed you are a lazyprogrammer :P you should add other cross browser properties to your answers too..

Comment: This is just wrong, Firefox supports this CSS property without prefix since version 4: http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you set the height of `html, body`.

By default, the `html` and `body` elements do not take up the entire height of the window. You have to explicitly set the height of `html, body` to force them to span the entire height of the window.

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

By forcing the `html, body` to take up the entire height of the window and then placing the `div { width:100%; height:100%; }` as a child of the `body` element you can ensure that the `div` will stretch to 100% of the window's width and height.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ewF8M/