# CSS background-attachement fixed doesn't work on Apple devices

Tags: html, css, iphone, ipad

How could I use background fixed property on iOS devices considering this CSS:

```
.sfondopertutti {
         background-attachment: fixed !important;
         background-image:url('../../sfondo.jpg');
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         min-height: 100%;
         background-position: center center;
         background-size: cover !important;
}
```

Works everywhere except on iPhone and iPad? I know this is an old question but I've found only old wrong solution to the problem and I don't know what to do.

Using a `position:fixed` div with background prevents page scrolling.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518845/fixed-background-for-part-of-a-site-div-in-ios

Comment: Also, after looking in to it more, it seems iphone/ipads do not support fixed backgrounds. It does seem that there are work-arounds, however. Here is a codepen that demonstrates one of the work arounds: https://codepen.io/callumfindlay/pen/VaYeoW

Comment: yes but position:fixed of div lock the scrolling of the whole page