# CSS: Image not showing on iOS devices

Tags: ios, css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

For some reason, my div of id "home" (landing image/screen) disappears on just iPhones when I run responsive test. Other mobile devices were fine, it's a PNG file so I'm not sure what is going on.

It's probably a simple CSS issue but nothing so far I've tried is working

http://productvisionclub.com/

Comment: Can you provide a code sample with the div/css you're referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the div that's disappearing, it's the background going white, and you can't see the logo because it's white-on-white.

`background-attachment: fixed` doesn't play nice with mobile (google it, e.g. [Fixed background image with ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443574/fixed-background-image-with-ios7)). If you remove that property, you can see the div, background and logo.