# Best practices for using Chrome DevTools

Tags: mobile, google-chrome-devtools

Working on a site and it looks good on the DevTools simulator but whacked on the phone (iPhoneX).

I found some questions about DevTools being off from actual views, a typical answer is "it's a simulator"

But I have also noticed that if I use px as a measurement instead of vh or % I get a more realistic view.

So, the general question is: What is the best way to get the best possible simulation out of DevTools (eg. like using the units as I mentioned above).

Comment: One wonders if the Wordpress theme makes a difference in how DevTools simulates.

Comment: Here's a short list of CSS that, when I got rid of these settings, Dev Tools looked like iPhone.  
padding-left, padding-right, padding-top, padding-bottom
background-size (using percentages or pixels)
background-attachment: fixed
background-position....and found a new items that looked at this stuff already.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504048/background-image-chrome-dev-tools-mobile-emulator-doesnt-match-actual-device