# why background-attachment:fixed on two divs that continuously arranged is not working in the ipad

Tags: css

css for the two divs listed below I have implemented its working in desktop versions but not supporting in ipad and mobile, I searched same issues in the stack overview but they are dealing with single background image mostly to the body, I am using two different divs and different background images, I want to fix the bg only actually divs are scrollable .

```
.cont_1{
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    background:#9ad5e3 url(../images/slide_1.png) center no-repeat; 
    background-attachment:fixed;
    -webkit-background-attachment:fixed;}

.cont_2{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding: 40px 0;
    background:#9ad5e3 url(../images/cont_1_bg_b.jpg) repeat;   
    background-attachment:fixed;
    -webkit-background-attachment:fixed;}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443574/fixed-background-image-with-ios7

Comment: great share, I made the change and it works.

Comment: I just noticed that there is a jerk while scrolling in ipad, any solution?