# Why Parallax effect doesn't work on mobile devices?

Tags: css, laravel-5

I am working with Laravel 5.4 application having parallax effect for the main background. It works perfectly fine on desktop, and also works perfect on varied screen size through developer tool, but when the same page is accessed via mobile device, the parallax effect doesn't show up.
I have added the block of code responsible for the needed effect.

```
#promo {
    min-height: 25em;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
<body>
<section id="promo" style="background: url({{$mainImg->path}}) 50% 0px repeat fixed; background-size:cover;">
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443574/fixed-background-image-with-ios7
There are limitations to background-position: fixed and background-size: cover for mobile devices.

Comment: tried using given media query with no luck...

Answer (score 1):

The background position fixed doesnt work properly on mobile devices so to fix this, you need to do a simple trick, rather then giving the `section` background image and make it fix, try to make `section:before` and set it to `position:fixed;` and give the backgroung image to it.

```
#promo:before{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
left:0;
top:0;
background:url('image.jpg');
}
```

play with z-index and here you go. try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your response Sandy!
I am generating dynamic path of the image, how will I be able to add the dynamic path with :before css?

Comment: Then you can try width an extra empty `div` in between section `<section><div background: url({{$mainImg->path}}) 50% 0px repeat></div></section>` and give the position fix to it.

Comment: Thanks for this! but this solution is not working for me

Comment: This will surely work, if not working for you, may be you are missing something, as i told you , you need to play with z-index as well

Comment: If I understand this correctly, if there would have been something wrong with z-index there would have been same result for desktop view as well.! Does z-index reacts as per the screen size??

Comment: here i mean when you set a div position fixed and it has background image as well, so it can cover you whole section and come on the top, so to manage this you need to make z-index in negative, in such a way that its not too much in negative that not visible

Comment: thanks.. did that with z-index 0, it work for desktop but not mobile device

Comment: try to use chrome and its mobile simulator to check why its not working properly, because without the code even i can not guess where the problem is