# Background image is too zoomed in on iphone

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone, background-image

Background image works fine on everything else but on iphones. the image looks like zoomed in too much.

Thanks in advance

```
.header {

min-height: 100vh;

background: url('/images.jpg') center/cover no-repeat fixed;
margin-top: auto;
padding: 13px 0px;
border-radius: 100px;
border-top-left-radius: 0 ;
border-top-right-radius: 0;
font-weight: bold;

color:white;
cursor: pointer;
border: 2px white;
margin-top: 0;
font-size: 12px;
background-size: cover;



<header class="header">
    <div class="hero">
        <h1 class="title"><img src="/images/Logo_big.png    " alt="logo" class="responsive"></h1>

        <a href="#contact" class="hero-button pulsate">About Us</a>

    </div>
```

Comment: Possibly related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443574/fixed-background-image-with-ios7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed background image with ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443574/fixed-background-image-with-ios7)

Answer (score 1):

Add this meta tag...

```css
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

is it helpful?

Comment: didnt change anything. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

Remove *fixed* in *background* property, like this:

```
background: url('/images.jpg') center/cover no-repeat;
```

There seems to be an issue around *background-attachment: fixed + background-size: cover* in Opera + IOs. This will remove the parallax effect but at least it wont be zoomed in.

For more info:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20444219/15100531
- [How to replicate background-attachment fixed on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios)