# Images not showing on IOS but fine in Chrome & Fireox

Tags: html, ios, image

Hoping someone can help me. I've built a website - http://luluplumbing.co.uk/ hosted on Amazon S3 and all images load fine in Chrome, Edge & Firefox but on IOS and Safari. The main image when the site loads is blank. All other images on the site are fine.

Another example on http://frankinstyyn.co.uk, image 2 on the geography round.

If it helps, I've added the CSS code of the file structure where other images are held...

```
 url('../images/main.jpg');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: illustrate please, which image do you mean on luluplumber? why should we guess?

Comment: Not sure how else to show you, it’s the first image on the page that is a black background, it should be a bathroom

Comment: what's the size of image & your mobile phone connection type & speed ?

Comment: I’m not sure how that’s relevant, image size varies and it happens on every iOS device, I have an iPhone 11 Pro with 250mbps speed. Like I say, it works on android fine.

Comment: "image size varies" – you mean you have some script to handle correct images for different devices? or resize by request?

Comment: Images are responsive and work on all android devices and Chrome, Firefox & edge but not at all on iOS and Safari devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this, it's most likely that your image is showing, just super zoomed in and broken due to fixed images not working on IOS - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443574/fixed-background-image-with-ios7) for more information.