# Background Cover Not Working on Samsung Internet

Tags: css, background-image, fixed, cover

Hellow there!

I have a css code like this. It correctly works in desktop browsers and android browsers except **samsung internet** browser. I must make this works in all browsers. So anyone please help me.

```
.image-movie-fixed-01{
  Background-image: url(../img/01.jpg);
  Background-repeat: no-repeat;
  Background-position: center center;
  
  Background-attachment: fixed;
  Background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: What version of Samsung Internet are you experiencing problems with?

Comment: Also, while CSS properties are ostensibly case-insensitive, its conventional to use lower-case.

Comment: Version 12.1.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, you cannot.

According to CanIUse.com, the Samsung Internet browser, version 12.x, does not support `background-attachment: fixed`.

https://caniuse.com/background-attachment

---

As for **why** it isn't supported, I *speculate* it's by-design:

- I believe it's disabled to improve battery-life on browsers because `fixed` backgrounds are expensive to repaint when scrolling.

  - iOS also didn't support `background-attachment: fixed` for the same reason:

    - [How to replicate background-attachment fixed on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios)
    - [Fixed background image with ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443574/fixed-background-image-with-ios7/44413493)
  - https://twitter.com/paul_irish/status/306818591196602368

    > Fixed-backgrounds have huge repaint cost and decimate scrolling performance, which is, I believe, why it was disabled.
- `background-attachment: fixed` dates back to CSS 1.0 in 1996. This is not a new feature that Samsung's developers simply haven't *gotten around* to implementing.
- Samsung Internet is based on Chromium, so it inherits all of Chromium's features.