# Fixed Background Image for Mobile with CSS

Tags: html, css

Using `@media` with CSS to fix the background image.  Logic tells me this should work, but I'm not getting any changed results after implementing this.  I've included the `body` code I'm working to overwrite as well.

Mobile:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
   body {
     background-position: center;
     background-attachment: fixed;
   }
}
```

Desktop:

```
body {
   height: 100%;
   background-image: url('../design/image.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-color: #333;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-attachment: fixed;` does not work on mobile webkit. There is a workaround, you can place the image inline in the html, set the position fixed and z-index below the content.

this is related [Using background-attachment:fixed in safari on the ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011226/using-background-attachmentfixed-in-safari-on-the-ipad)