# background-attachment:fixed not working on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

Though it's a very common question but really could not find the proper solution of this query.I want when scroll down the background image should remain fixed and the texts will be scrolling only and it's working fine in computer but in case of mobile screen it's doing normal scroll not that scroll like computer, the picture is also scrolling with the text,

```
#sectionone{
  background-image:url(../img/mainimg.jpeg);
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Probably you should consider this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352838/fixed-background-image-for-mobile-with-css

Comment: That link does not providing any clear indication,Would you please tell me what should be the code

Comment: In media query apply `!important` maybe this will work otherwise post fiddle of your code.

Comment: What I mean is `background-attachment: fixed;` does not work on mobile webkit which indicates in the link.

Comment: You should try this jQuery plugin http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/parallax_sections.html

Comment: Safari has Partial Support for `background-attachment` https://caniuse.com/#search=background-attachment