# How can we fix "background-attachment: fixed" in mobile devices for parallax designs?

Tags: html, css, parallax, background-attachment

I'm implementing parallax scrolling in my website, but it is not working in the mobile devices, I don't know how to implement it for mobile devices. I think this is because, the mobile displays are touch screens, so we have to use fingers to scroll where as in PC we can scroll with mouse. Thanks in advance.

```css
.section1 {
  background: url(https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1465420961937-e0eba4dda519) no-repeat fixed center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.section2 {
  background: url(https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1462121457351-9fb0f5622b72) no-repeat fixed center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.section3 {
  background: url(https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1465420961937-e0eba4dda519) no-repeat fixed center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section1"></div>
<div class="section2"></div>
<div class="section3"></div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a snippet - that way we can try your code on mobile devices.

Comment: @Andreas Is it okay now?

Comment: Sorry but I can't see any implementation of parallax scrolling in your code...

Comment: @Andreas it is just a basic parallax implementation using fixed background

Comment: I see, sorry! I've edited your code to a snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the `background: fixed;` rule does indeed not work on mobile (webkit) browsers. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011226/using-background-attachmentfixed-in-safari-on-the-ipad) for a possible workaround.

Comment: But I heard that there are some plugins to do this in both Android and apple products