# issue with cut off on background image set on body - iOS/Safari

Tags: ios, css, iphone, ipad

I've implemented a background image on the `<body>` element of the following website: http://www.bestdiscointown.co.uk/dev/ - this is so that an image is displayed while the user is scrolling to the bottom of the page (the following screenshot shows this working in Firefox):

[image]

This is achieved with the following CSS and holds up well in the majority of web browsers:

```
body {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'proxima_nova_ththin';
    background-image:  url("custom-assets/img/body_bg.jpg");  
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

However when viewed in Safari on iOS 9.3.5 the following issue occurs and the background image cuts off:

[image]

1. Is there a reason for this issue occurring, could it be that I have set   `background-attachment: fixed;`?
2. Can a fix be applied in my CSS to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS is known to not keep backgrounds fixed (via `background-attachment: fixed`) due to supposed performance issues. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23420490/1887218

You can do a workaround, and add the background to a full-screen wrapper, that has `position: fixed` set. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770538/1887218

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing background-size: cover; or you have to repeat your background

```
body {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'proxima_nova_ththin';
    background-image:  url("custom-assets/img/body_bg.jpg");  
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```